# Node.js + MongoDB update operation confirmation

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In Node.js, I have (briefly) this script:

```
var http = require('http');
var XmlStream = require('xml-stream');
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var tims = { ... };

var db = new mongo.Db('tims', new mongo.Server("127.0.0.1", 27017, {}), {w: 1});
db.open(function(e, db) {
    var req = http.get({
        host: tims.uri,
        path: '/xml/'+tims.database+tims.services.database
    }).on('response', function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        cProjects = db.collection("projects");
        var xml = new XmlStream(res);

        xml.on('updateElement: Tims ProjectID', function(project) {
            // console.log(project.$text+' - '+project.$.title);
            cProjects.update({project_id: project.$text}, {project_id: project.$text, title: project.$.title}, {upsert:true}, function(err, result) {
                console.log('result: '+result);
            });     
        });

        xml.on('end', function(data) {
            db.close();
        });

    });
});
```

I am using a Node.js package called [xml-stream](https://github.com/assistunion/xml-stream) that pieces together response chunks from Node to get valid XML before processing. My problem: if I leave out

```
xml.on('end', function(data) {
    db.close();
});
```

my connection never closes and the console just hangs. The upside is that `console.log('result: '+result);` writes to the console and I can see that my data was committed successfully. So if I leave in the `end` event and close the DB once all XML has been processed, the Node instance terminates before `console.log('result: '+result)` is written.

I am a newbie to both MongoDB and Node.js, so I was curious what the best practice is here for confirmation, or perhaps a simple pointing out of what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `'end'` event is occurring before all the `update` callbacks have completed.  So you need to rework your code a bit to keep track of the number of updates still pending and only call `db.close()` once both the `'end'` event has fired and all the pending updates have completed.

So something like this:

```
db.open(function(e, db) {
    var req = http.get({
        host: tims.uri,
        path: '/xml/'+tims.database+tims.services.database
    }).on('response', function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        cProjects = db.collection("projects");
        var xml = new XmlStream(res);
        var end = false;
        var pending = 0;

        xml.on('updateElement: Tims ProjectID', function(project) {
            // console.log(project.$text+' - '+project.$.title);
            ++pending;
            cProjects.update({project_id: project.$text}, {project_id: project.$text, title: project.$.title}, {upsert:true}, function(err, result) {
                console.log('result: '+result);
                if (--pending === 0 && end) {
                    db.close();
                }
            });     
        });

        xml.on('end', function(data) {
            end = true;
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: I can't wait to get to the office and try this out!